# How do I extract individual glyphs from a bitmap font?

Tags: image-processing, fonts, bitmap-fonts

I have a bitmap font sheet, and I would like to have each glyph as its own separate image.  Do I just need to manually find the width of each glyph and extract them one by one, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to do it once, a quick and simple way is to just display each character in a window and do a screen capture, then split that image into pieces. If you use something that recognizes Tab characters you can get them evenly spaced so that you don't have to measure more than one character.